# Is it possible to modify the default delete behaviour on a custom object?

Tags: salesforce

Is it possible to modify the default delete action on custom object records so that it prompts for a password before deleting? And if it is, how do I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't get the user password for security reasons. You can only reset it if you need to but there is no way to get nor the password or the hash. But if means not SF user password, but something other, you can to create custom page layout (using Visualforce) with controller (on Apex) for your object, where you override Delete Button behavior.

Comment: It's not the main SF user password - just an additional layer of security that my client is wanting. Thanks for the answer!